# Is there a naming convention for the return type of custom react hooks?

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-hooks, graphql, apollo-client

I wrote a custom hook named `useFetchClientData` and am looking for a naming convention for the return type for that hook.

GraphQL is using generics for their custom hooks, but I am not sure if that is a convention or just their way of dealing with it. Also I can't really say if that is a good approach or not.

```
export function useUpdatePhoneNumberMutation(baseOptions?: Apollo.MutationHookOptions<UpdatePhoneNumberMutation, UpdatePhoneNumberMutationVariables>) {
        const options = {...defaultOptions, ...baseOptions}
        return Apollo.useMutation<UpdatePhoneNumberMutation, UpdatePhoneNumberMutationVariables>(UpdatePhoneNumberDocument, options);
      }
export type UpdatePhoneNumberMutationHookResult = ReturnType<typeof useUpdatePhoneNumberMutation>;
```

Comment: What's wrong with generics? But instead of `ReturnType`, I would recommend to spell out the `Apollo.MutationTuple<UpdatePhoneNumberMutation, UpdatePhoneNumberMutationVariables>` when declaring your type alias.

Comment: Nothing wrong with it, I just don't feel confident enough with Typescript to validate that approach.

Comment: Apollo *must* use generics, it's the only proper way to model the type of `useMutation`.